# How to sequentially write a stream in Node in a loop with writeable Streams?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I want to append lines to a file, which is a writeable stream, in Node, in a specific order, through a loop.

Here is a simplified version of what I am talking about:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var outfile = fs.createWriteStream('outfile.txt');

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    outfile.write('i', function (err, len) {
        console.log('written');
    });
}
```

I need the file to be written sequentially meaning that it would write, `12345...etc` in order.  My understanding is that `outfile.write` is async, meaning that it is possible for the file to be written out of order - is this correct?

I see from the node docs

> Note that it is unsafe to use fs.write multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback. For this scenario, fs.createWriteStream is strongly recommended.

So I believe that using a stream is best, however, I am not sure hot to guarantee that the data chunk was written succesfully before moving on to the next iteration in the loop.  How should I go about doing that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think with both the current streams and the streams you had in 2015 the write was never async parallel. Write streams have a buffer in memory and you write to that buffer not to the hard disk directly. The buffer will keep your sequence in the right order.

Answer (score -3):

You can avoid using `fs.createWriteStream` by using [`fs.writeSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position) which doesn't have a callback problem like `fs.write`

Comment: I am not a fan of this because of the synchronous and blocking nature of the code.

Comment: In your scenario, blocking is what is needed by definition of the problem.

Comment: @RūdolfsVikmanis, the `Writable` object has been designed for writing sequential data. That's why it is called `stream`, so using writeSync() when you can take advantage of streaming functionality is foolish.